# Projecting into KeyValuePair via EF / Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, projection, keyvaluepair

I'm trying to load a list of KeyValuePairs from an EF / Linq query like this:

```
return (from o in context.myTable 
select new KeyValuePair<int, string>(o.columnA, o.columnB)).ToList();
```

My problem is that this results in the error

> "Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in
>   LINQ to Entities."

Is there an easy way around this? I know I could create a custom class for this instead of using KeyValuePair but that does seem like re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Discussion on Aggregation as an alternative option: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/513350db-6f1e-4930-87e9-81a04f574b54/linq-select-projection-vs-classic-for-loop-which-one-is-better

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Select only columnA and columnB from your table, and move further processing in memory:

```
return context.myTable
              .Select(o => new { o.columnA, o.columnB }) // only two fields
              .AsEnumerable() // to clients memory
              .Select(o => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(o.columnA, o.columnB))
              .ToList();
```

Consider also to create dictionary which contains KeyValuePairs:

```
return context.myTable.ToDictionary(o => o.columnA, o => o.columnB).ToList();
```

Comment: NB: the reason this works is because LINQ-to-Entities only supports parameterless constructors, so you can't use `new KeyValuePair...`. LINQ-to-Collections does support constructors with parameters. When you call `AsEnumerable()` it evaluates the EF query and it's then LINQ-to-Collections that handles the following `.Select()`

Comment: How would one implement an ASYNC version of this? There is no `AsEnumerableAsync()` method.

Comment: @Zapnologica - Replace `AsEnumerable()` with `ToListAsync()` then wrap the `await` out to the end of `ToListAsync` with parenthesis and append the `.Select(o => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(o.columnA, o.columnB)).ToList();`  Refactor as needed.

Answer (score 9):

Since LINQ to Entities does not support `KeyValuePair`, you should turns to LINQ to Object by using `AsEnumerable` first:

```
return context.myTable
              .AsEnumerable()
              .Select(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(o.columnA, o.columnB))
              .ToList();
```

Comment: although this works, it's inefficient as it loads all columns from myTable

Comment: .Select(o=> new KeyValuePair<int, string>(o.columnA, o.columnB))

Answer (score 3):

With recent versions of EF Core selecting into KeyValuePair appears to work fine. I also verified that (on MS SQL Server) the SQL only selects the two relevant fields, so the "Select" is actually translated:

```
return context.myTable 
    .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(o.columnA, o.columnB))
    .ToList();

SELECT [m].[columnA], [m].[columnB]
FROM [myTable] AS [m]
```

The generated SQL is the same as for anonymous classes, except that renames are only made for the latter (e.g. "AS A"):

```
return context.myTable 
    .Select(x => new {A = o.columnA, B = o.columnB})
    .ToList();

SELECT [m].[columnA] AS [A], [m].[columnB] AS [B]
FROM [myTable] AS [m]
```

Tested with .NET 6.

Note that using a Dictionary (as suggested in other answers) will introduce additional constraints compared to a List of KeyValuePairs:

- The order of Dictionary entries is undefined. Thus, while one (currently) typically has the same order of elements for filling in and enumerating over a Dictionary, this is not guaranteed (I've already seen cases of reordering) and might change without notice in the future.
- The key values in a Dictionary must be unique (which may or may not apply to columnA in the database, and would cause an exception if columnA is not).
- Dictionary does not allow "null" for the key (This is just for completeness, since the OP uses "int" type for the key anyway).
- The Dictionary keeps an index of its keys, so setting it up might take longer than just having a list of KeyValuePairs (though this is micro-optimisation ...)

Depending on the use case of the OP (which I cannot deduce from the question), some of these constraints might be desirable, though, and the Dictionary might actually be the solution.

Comment: It should be noted that this only works if it happens in the final `Select` because EF doesn't try to translate it into SQL. Add a `Where` after it and EF has to translate it, and fails. Nevertheless, it can be useful to exploit this auto-switching to this so-called *client-side evaluation* in the final select.

Comment: Noted. I can't really think of a use case where I would project into a KVP before other filtering/processing steps, though. It might be easier to just use the fields/columns directly in the subsequent command or project into an anonymous class for the intermediate step.

Answer (score 0):

There is also alternative, when you want to store multiple values for one key exists something what is called **Lookup**.

> Represents a collection of keys each mapped to one or more values.

Here you have some official [documentations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb460184(v=vs.110).aspx).

More over **lookup** seems to be much faster than *Dictionary < TKey, List < TValue > >.*